# Cannot redeclare maybe_create_table()

Tags: errors

I have been experiencing a mysterious error whenever I activate *any* plugin on WP 4.2.1:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare maybe_create_table() (previously
>   declared in /wp-admin/install-helper.php:52) in
>   /wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php on line 1616

The plugin is activated though when I navigate away from the error screen.

To my surprise, there is a lot of entries about this error when searching google, but not a single solution is posted, or a cause of this error. I have looked through every single search result.

There is this [7 year old trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/6747) discussing `maybe_create_table()` being declared in two instances but that is marked as solved.

What in the world is this? What is the cause of it?

Comment: Do you have this problem with a pristine install-- no plugins, no extra themes? Browsing the source, I can see why this would happen but it is hard to see how this particular issue would slip into a major release.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Can you please explain in which instances this could happen? How can I debug this and find the cause? This is a sandbox install. I deactivated all plugins and used one of the Twenty* themes. The error is still present whenever I activate a plugin. There are of course *deactivated* plugins there and one custom theme which is not active. Not that this would be a problem but thought I would mention.

Comment: Try comparing the newest upgrade.php with yours? It shouldn't actually redeclare it.

Comment: @FrederikSpang Are you asking me to compare my local upgrade.php with a fresh install version? It is identical, I just checked.

Comment: In that case, the error is very weird. I've never seen it before, to be honest.
Which version have you installed?

Comment: @FrederikSpang Latest version: 4.2.1 -- it is very strange, given that if you google this error, you will see that many people have come across it but there have never been any actual info about why and how...

Comment: I don't believe your upgrade.php is entirely correct.. My upgrade.php doesn't have that function on that line at all? (Mine is the latest version directly from SVN, though!)

Comment: I've narrowed it down. Upgrade.php is loaded AFTER install-helper.php, which causes the error. I don't know why, but the loadorder of the files is wrong, somehow.. It doesn't happen on my setup though..

Comment: Both `wp-admin/install-helper.php` and `wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php`declare a function named `maybe_create_table`. The `install-helper.php` function is wrapped in `if ( ! function_exists('maybe_create_table') ) :` but the other one isn't. If `install-helper.php` loads first the function declaration in `upgrade.php` will trigger the error you see. I don't know why that sequence would happen.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Thanks for the info. For the record, I am not seeing this error anymore, although since yesterday, I did not do anything to solve it. We will keep this question alive here though given that there have been and will be more users with this issue who will find their way here.

Comment: I just had this problem, so I started searching for it. When I found this comment section, I went back to the site (about 5 minutes after the 1st time the problem presented itself) and just a refresh did the trick. The bug resolved itself. We need more bugs like this.